# How to run script on next page?

Tags: javascript

I've just written a Javascript code to edit highlight product with another. You can see the code in a snippet.

The code works nicely on the first page. When I click on "Load more products" or "Next page" the script is not working and I can't figure out why.

Thank you :-)

```js
<script>
var strMessage1 = document.getElementById("content") ;
strMessage1.innerHTML = strMessage1.innerHTML
                        .replace(/highlight-product col-sm-12 col-md-8/g,'col-sm-6 col-md-4 certain-product');
function paxioProduct() {
    var href = $(".certain-product").find(".name").attr("href");
    $(".certain-product .tools-wrap").append('<a href="' + href + '" class="product-link"> </a>');
    $(".certain-product .tools-wrap").append('<a href="' + href + '" class="btn btn-detail">Detail</a>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    paxioProduct();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {

});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".certain-product .img").insertBefore($(".certain-product .descr"));
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".certain-product .btn-detail").insertAfter($(".certain-product .btn.visible-lg-inline-block"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry you seem to be missing most of the script in the example your question was related to, it's also a bit hard to understand what your goal is. please provide a full example so we can help you out :)

Comment: If this is script direct from your project then it looks like you're missing `paxioProduct()` in your `ajaxComplete` callback. Try adding that in and see if it resolves the error.

Comment: @digital-pollution What exactly do you mean? :-) 

I have product page with 9 products which someone is set to highlight. I just using this script to show highlighted product as the other (the highight product has different CSS and size). This scripts runs perfectly but when I click on product page 2, 3 etc., the script is not working.

Comment: yes but we cant see that, is it an XHR do does it fully reload the page with new data? what does "show highlighted product as the other" mean?

Comment: @digital-pollution Well, you can see example there -> https://248435.myshoptet.com/do-domacnosti/

If you go to page 2, you will see highlight product, then go back to page 1and see it too. Because the script is not run again when page is load.

Comment: looking at the example url you will need to run paxioProduct() again after the XHR request has completed. where it is the code of that site, couldn't tell ya.

Comment: @digital-pollution I need to run the first script again with .replace function. If I use ajaxComplete, than it works but the images not showing up with images (see again the URL above) with error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). Do you know why? :-)

Comment: for the first part just wrap the jquery .replace stuff in a function that you can call again exactly as you've done with the paxioProduct() function. The 404 means that the file requested was not found, could be caused by many things.

Comment: @digital-pollution Yeah, that's what I did. But now with the function the images of products which are after the highlight product is not showing up. If I turn that script with ajaxComplete off the images is showing up (but the script is not working on next page). I am really disappointed.

Comment: likely something is breaking further up the chain, perhaps the method that is moving the img tag around is messing up the DOM, but thats just speculation without a complete example it'll be hard to help you.